# Indexing first n characters of Charfield in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to index a specific number of Characters on Django Charfield?

For example, this is how we index fields in Django, but I guess it applies to entire field or all characters.

```
class Meta:
       indexes = [
           models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name',]),
           models.Index(fields=['-date_of_birth',]),
]
```

So, how to apply index to specific portion of field as shown in mysql below.

```sql
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

Comment: Please include your attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a functional index with the [**`Substr`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#substr):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

# …

class Meta:
       indexes = [
           models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name']),
           models.Index(fields=['-date_of_birth']),
           models.Index(Substr('pub_date', 0, 10), name='part_of_name')
       ]
```

Comment: (but making queries generated by the ORM actually use that index may be a hairier problem, I think...)

Comment: @AKX: yes, likely it will only work when filtering with `Substr('pub_date')``. Might be that this is too specific to a database dialect to implement this in Django (without creating some extra logic).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  

`indexes = [models.Index(Substr("name1", 1, 10), name="part_of_name")]
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given`

Comment: @msvstl: you can only use functional indexes since Django-4.0.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the info, I used it in a lesser version. Any reference would be appreciated. I found in this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/indexes/)  can be used from 3.2.